# Use jQuery to navigate away from page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I will only have a relative link available to me but I want to use jQuery to navigate to this rel link.  I only see AJAX functionality in jQuery.  How can I do this using jQuery or just pure HTML/JavaScript?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Other answers rightly point out that there is no need to use jQuery in order to navigate to another URL; that's why there's no jQuery function which does so!

If you're asking how to click a link via jQuery then assuming you have markup which looks like:

```
<a id="my-link" href="/relative/path.html">Click Me!</a>
```

You could [`click()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/click) it by executing:

```
$('#my-link').click();
```

Comment: calling click() doesn't really navigate the page for you, does it?  It will run the any attached click handlers, but it won't follow the href.

Comment: click() generates a normal JavaScript click event so it should work, but you run into problems you try something like: $('#mydiv').click(function(){ $('#mylink').click() }); where #mylink is inside #mydiv -- this will result in an "endless" loop (really a "too much recursion" exception). If you want to navigate, it is safer to use: window.location.href = $('#mylink').attr("href");

Answer (score 182):

```
window.location.href = "/somewhere/else";
```

Comment: I believe .href is technically the 'correct' way to do it, although both have worked since Netscape 2.

Answer (score 7):

```
window.location = myUrl;
```

Anyway, this is not jQuery: it's plain javascript

Comment: This no longer works in Chome/Chromium. Use window.location.href instead.

Comment: I just tested using Chrome Version 37.0.2062.94 for Mac and it works. But you are correct: the complete statement should be used.