# How to pass an object from one view to another

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Hi I have to pass an object value on select of grid row to another view.
My code cshtml code is

```
var gview = $("#grdSearch").data("kendoGrid");

var selectedItem = gview.dataItem(gview.select());
if (selectedItem.address != undefined) {
    alert(selectedItem.address);
    window.location = '../PageSearch/Select?value:' + selectedItem;
}
else
    alert("NO Row Is SELECTED");
```

My controller code is

```
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult Select(Search value)
    {
        return Json(value, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The problem is that the jQuery code is calling controller action be `selectedItem` is null.
How to access data inside `selectedItem`?

Comment: and how is gview.dataItem(gview.select()); supposed to have any value??

Comment: Hi Rex the grid row will have the value of type class Select. The if condition is executed that means it has taken data from grid but is not able to pass it to the controller. So am I doing wrong in syntax for window.location?

Comment: '../PageSearch/Select?value:' + selectedItem; shouldn't it be '../PageSearch/Select?value=' + selectedItem;

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need: `window.location.href` as seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1207465/599180

I don't think selectedItem is going to serialize to a string so you may need `JSON.stringify(selectedItem)` as seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21595823/599180

You'll have to make sure your parameter type for Select() matches the fields that selectedItem serializes to that you care about.

Answer (score 0):

Data passed in the querystring needs to be in the form `?key1=val1&key2=val2&key3=val3`

So to pass object property values in the querystring you need to convert your javascript object to this querystring format e.g:

```
'../PageSearch/Select?address=' + selectedItem.address + '&somethingElse=' + selectedItem.somethingElse`
```

An easier way to get the data to the server would be to POST it with jQuery:

```
$.post( "../PageSearch/Select", selectedItem );
```

There's lots more info about jQuery post at https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/